# Update SQL Server query with order by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL Server query that I would like to add order by clause. Can someone take a look at the QRY.

```
declare @variable int
set @variable = 0

UPDATE r_recipes_tmp
SET @variable = stepId = @variable + 1
```

I was trying the following with no luck.

```
declare @variable int
set @variable = 0

UPDATE r_recipes_tmp
SET @variable = stepId = @variable + 1 
WHERE stepId IN (SELECT stepId 
                 FROM r_recipes_tmp 
                 WHERE recipename = 'test' 
                 ORDER BY stepid DESC)
```

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have an order by in an update.

Comment: What John said, an order by in the sub query would make no difference in the end result of data that gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* like you want to sort the rows in the descending order of `stepId`, then assign new consecutive values to `stepId` but this time in the ascending order, so essentially you want to reverse the order of rows if `stepId` was the sorting criterion. Or, using an example (which you haven't provided), turn a row set like this:

```
stepId  someColumn
------  ----------
7       AAA
4       BBB
2       DDD
1       CCC
```

into this:

```
stepId  someColumn
------  ----------
1       AAA
2       BBB
3       DDD
4       CCC
```

If that is indeed so and if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) like this:

```
WITH newIDs AS (
  SELECT
    stepId,
    newStepId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stepId DESC)
  FROM atable
)
UPDATE newIDs
SET stepId = newStepId
;
```

The ROW_NUMBER function assigns row numbers in the descending order of `stepId`, returning them alongside corresponding current values of `stepId`. Since the `newIDs` CTE derives rows from a single table, that makes the CTE updatable, so you can use it as the target of UPDATE and simply assign every `stepId` the newly generated row number.

Comment: I am recieving "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'" error when running your query.

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my side. The `PARTITION BY` should in fact be `ORDER BY`. Please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank You. I am attempting to order by "stepid" then renumber the values. Your qry works at renumbering but does not order first then renumber. Unless I missed something my data stayed in the same order. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I guess I can't tell you what you did *wrong* if I don't know what you *did*. Perhaps it would be easier to find the problem if you could show your adapted version of the query, preferably at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), with a data sample to run it against (so that we could see the issue). Alternatively, you could simply update your question with an actual example that I (and anyone else) could work with. Then I myself could give you a SQL Fiddle demo of a working version.

Comment: I used your code ---Works well -- WITH newIDs AS (
  SELECT
    stepId,
    newStepId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stepId ASC)
  FROM atable
)
UPDATE newIDs
SET stepId = newStepId
;